# Graphs that "polygonize" a manifold

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

It's rather easy to conceptualize a covering of the [Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) by a countable set of convex but otherwise arbitrarily sized and shaped polygons (seen as subsets of the plane) without overlaps. It can - without loss of generality? - be required that two such polygons do share exactly one complete edge or none.

[image]

> Is there an official name of such a covering?

I guess "polygonization of the plane" is not utterly wrong, but misses some aspects: convexity and uniqueness of shared edges.

Anyway: a polygonization of the plane induces an (infinite) graph with obvious vertices and edges.

> (How) can such a graph be characterized?
> ("A graph is induced by a polygonization of the plane iff it is planar, [2-edge-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185965/1792), and ...")

The Euclidean plane is not the only manifold that can be polygonized in the way described above: there are polygonizations of the sphere, the torus and so on and so on.

> (How) can the graphs be characterized, that polygonize *any* manifold?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but what the concept you are looking for looks pretty much like a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

An excerpt form Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, a Voronoi diagram is a partitioning of a plane into
>   regions based on distance to points in a specific subset of the plane.
>   That set of points (called seeds, sites, or generators) is specified
>   beforehand, and for each seed there is a corresponding region
>   consisting of all points closer to that seed than to any other. These
>   regions are called Voronoi cells. The Voronoi diagram of a set of
>   points is dual to its Delaunay triangulation.

And this is how it looks like (credits to Wikipedia):

[image]

There is a quite easy to follow algorithm to generate a Voronoi diagram of a given space. Basically you will require a "seed" of points to make the partitions. They can be random, so the cells will be random every time you apply the procedure from scratch.

Some time ago I was also trying to understand how it is applied, here is [a Voronoi diagram of a Sierpinski attractor](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1613090/189215).

[image]

Comment: This concept is too strict: surely there are convex polygonal tesselations which don't arise from Voronoi diagrams.  It's interesting to see whether the set of graphs is still the same; I suspect they aren't, but a counterexample would be nice to see.