# Are the vertices of a Voronoi diagram obtained from a Sierpinski attractor also a kind of attractor?

Tags: fractals, random-graphs, chaos-theory, tessellations, voronoi-diagram

Trying to understand how the [Voronoi Diagrams](http://files.righto.com/fractals/vor.html) work I did a test generating the Voronoi diagram of the points obtained from [The Chaos Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game) algorithm when it is applied to a $3$-gon. The result is a set of points part of the [Sierpinski attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle), the Voronoi cells and the vertices of each cell.

This is a little animation of the first 200 steps of The Chaos Game for a $3$-gon and how the Voronoi diagram is generated:

[image]

And this is how it looks like a Voronoi Diagram applied to TCG after $2000$ steps:

[image]

**Update 2016/01/25**: as suggested by @Mark McClure in the comments, here is the result of the Voronoi diagram applied directly to the Sierpinski gasket (recursion level $6$).

[image]

I would like to ask the following question:

> 1. If the Voronoi diagram is using the Sierpinski attractor points as the seeds or generators of each cell, are the vertices then a kind of attractor as well?
> 2. I was not able to find papers or references about this kind of test (obtaining the Voronoi diagram of an attractor). Are there any papers or references?
> 3. For what other attractors would be interesting to obtain a Voronoi diagram? (I am working currently in a TCG $4$-gon algorithm, I will try to add the results in some days)

I am asking this because the vertices are partitioning the space according to the Sierpinski attractor, so I wonder if they will inherit some properties of the attractor (like being an attractor itself, or some special orientation of the [Voronoi poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_pole), etc.).

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend that you try it with a [regular image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle#/media/File:Sierpinski_triangle.svg) generated by a deterministic algorithm. I think it will probably be easier to see the convergence of your Voronoi vertices in that case.

Comment: @MarkMcClure added, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: That does look pretty cool!